# How can I show header on a page that contains only footer data in VS2010 report?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, rdlc

I have set `RepeatOnNewPage = True` and `KeepWithGroup = After` so the header is repeated correctly on every page that contains at least one detail.

But the header is not visible if a page contains only footer data (I have a lot of rows in the footer, each one with different calculation of details data).

How can I show the header on this type of page (without recurring to workarounds like passing a DataSet containings everything I need to show in the report)?